# map each post to the user who posted it by foreign key in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I want to connect each post with the logged in user who posted it.

models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Campagin(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    media = models.FileField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=220)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title`
```

As you can see the posts were made by two different users, but the relation shows that it is made by the first user [image]

this image shows the registered users.. [image]

Views.py

```
class NewCampagin(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'campagin/new_campagin.html'
    model = Campagin
    fields = ['title','media','description']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('campagin:active_campagin')
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The problem seems to be that `user_id` always has the default value `1`. Can you post the code, that creates the campaign instances?

Comment: Can you post your form class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so `CreateView` allows you to specify the `model` and `fields` attributes to **implicitly** create a form for you. It's quite neat for quick form submissions but in your case, you will need to make some customizations before saving the `Campaign` object into the database (linking up the current **logged in** user).

As a result, you will need to create your own form first (create a file called `forms.py` which can be next to your `views.py`) and enter this code:

```
class CampaignForm(ModelForm): #  Import ModelForm too.

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # We need to get access the currently logged in user so set it as an instance variable of CampaignForm.
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)  
        super(CampaignForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Campaign # you need to import this from your models.py class
        fields = ['title','media','description']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # This is where we need to insert the currently logged in user into the Campaign instance.

        instance = super(CampaignForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # Once the all the other attributes are inserted, we just need to insert the current logged in user
        # into the instance.
        instance.user = self.user

        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Now that we have our `forms.py` all ready to go we just need to modify your `views.py`:

```
class NewCampagin(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    template_name = 'campagin/new_campagin.html'
    form_class = forms.CampaignForm # Again, you'll need to import this carefully from our newly created forms.py
    model = models.Campaign # Import this.
    queryset = models.Campaign.objects.all()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('campagin:active_campagin')  # Sending user object to the form, to verify which fields to display/remove (depending on group)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # In order for us to access the current user in CampaignForm, we need to actually pass it accross.
        # As such, we do this as shown below.
        kwargs = super(NewCampaign, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

## What's actually happening with my POST requests under the bonnet??

> Note: This is just extra information for the sake of learning. You do
>   not need to read this part if you don't care about how your class
>   based view is actually handling your post request.

Essentially `CreateView` looks like this:

```
class CreateView(SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseCreateView):
    """
    View for creating a new object instance,
    with a response rendered by template.
    """
    template_name_suffix = '_form'
```

Doesn't look that interesting but if we analyse `BaseCreateView`:

```
class BaseCreateView(ModelFormMixin, ProcessFormView):
    """
    Base view for creating an new object instance.

    Using this base class requires subclassing to provide a response mixin.
    """


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.object = None
       return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

we can see we are inheriting from two very important classes `ModelFormMixin` and `ProcessFormView`. Now the line, `return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)`, essentially calls the `post` function in `ProcessFormView` which looks like this:

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then checked for validity.
        """
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

As you can see, your `CreateView` really just boils down to this small `post` function which simply gets a specified form and validates + saves it. There's 2 questions to ask at this point.

***1)*** What does `form = self.get_form()` do since I didn't even specify my form? 
***2)*** What is `self.form_valid(form)` actually doing?

To answer the first question, `self.get_form()` essentially calls another function `form_class = self.get_form_class()` and this function is actually found in **ModelFormMixin** (the one where inherited from!):

```
def get_form_class(self):
    """
    Returns the form class to use in this view.
    """
    if self.fields is not None and self.form_class:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "Specifying both 'fields' and 'form_class' is not permitted."
        )
    if self.form_class:
        return self.form_class
    else:
        if self.model is not None:
            # If a model has been explicitly provided, use it
            model = self.model
        elif hasattr(self, 'object') and self.object is not None:
            # If this view is operating on a single object, use
            # the class of that object
            model = self.object.__class__
        else:
            # Try to get a queryset and extract the model class
            # from that
            model = self.get_queryset().model

        if self.fields is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Using ModelFormMixin (base class of %s) without "
                "the 'fields' attribute is prohibited." % self.__class__.__name__
            )
        # THIS IS WHERE YOUR FORM WAS BEING IMPLICITLY CREATED.
        return model_forms.modelform_factory(model, fields=self.fields)
```

As you can see, this function is where your form was being **implicitly** created (see very last line). We needed to add more functionality in your case so we created our own `forms.py` and specified **form_class** in the `views.py` as a result.

To answer the second question, we need to look at the function (`self.form_valid(form)`) call's source code:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """
    If the form is valid, save the associated model.
    """
    # THIS IS A CRUCIAL LINE. 
    # This is where your actual Campaign object is created. We OVERRIDE the save() function call in our forms.py so that you could link up your logged in user to the campaign object before saving.
    self.object = form.save() 
    return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

So here we are simply saving the object.

I hope this helps you!

More information at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview

Comment: I get an error **NewCampagin is missing a QuerySet. Define NewCampagin.model, NewCampagin.queryset, or override NewCampagin.get_queryset().**

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /campagin/new/
Exception Value: NewCampagin is missing a QuerySet. Define NewCampagin.model, NewCampagin.queryset, or override NewCampagin.get_queryset().

Comment: Oh just add queryset=models.Campaign.objects.all() right under the form_class instance variable. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: "Using ModelFormMixin (base class of %s) without "
                "the 'fields' attribute is prohibited." 
i Get this error..

Comment: What django version are you using?

Comment: Please see my edited answer - I have added the `model` instance variable back to `NewCampaign`.